# Configure Windows Hello to allow Login only with PIN not fingerprint

Tags: passwords, login, group-policy, fingerprint, windows-hello

In light of the [recently discovered flaws with fingerprint readers](https://www.theverge.com/2023/11/22/23972220/microsoft-windows-hello-fingerprint-authentication-bypass-security-vulnerability), I want to configure Windows Hello to allow Login/Unlock of Locked Computer only with PIN and not using fingerprint. When logged in/unlocked fingerprint could be used as well.

(How) Is it possible to set this up?

Comment: Remove the fingerprint and that will accomplish what you want.

Comment: @cachius: Do you mean [like this](https://consumer.huawei.com/en/support/content/en-us15854144/) ?